# Get only the image path from cms block?

Tags: magento-1.9, web-services

I want get path of image of `cms-block` and here is code:

```
$yourPageIdentifier   = 'home_banner';
$cmsPage              = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId($store_id)->load($yourPageIdentifier,'identifier');
$array['title']       = $cmsPage->getTitle();
$array['identifier']  = $cmsPage->getIdentifier();
$array['content']     = htmlentities($cmsPage->getContent());
```

Help me get this.

Comment: you want to get all images from cms content ?

Comment: yah! you are right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
    $processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor(); 
    $html = $processor->filter($array['content']);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);

    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
           echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: working fine but i get "image": [
      "{{media url=",
      "{{media url=",
      "{{media url="
    ]

Comment: after media url there is no image path

Comment: I have updated the answer plz check